# Selecting rows from a multiselect

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, multi-select

I have an html `<select id="nr_s_actors">` DOM object. Inside the `<select>` I have many different `<option>`s tags with different ids. How do I set them to be selected?

I have turned my `<select>` object into a fancy jQuery **multiselect** by calling the code 
`$("#nr_s_actors").multiselect();`
and all that works just fine (visually) but I cannot set it's selected options and have it visually display anymore.

Below is my ajax json call. I get my data back correctly and the var called **id** is correct. The ids of my options are 'id_actor_X' where X is a number. (which I get from the parameter `value[0]`)

```
$.ajax(
 { 
    url: 'phpscripts/getreportrelations.php', 
    data: 'reportid=' + aData[0], 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data,function(index,value)
        {
                var id="id_actor_"+value[0];
                //Assume the var id is correctly set to the id of the option. 

                //what goes here?
        });
    },
    error: function (header, status, error) 
    {
        console.log('ajax answer post returned error ' + header + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should add your html / js code.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out all I needed was $("#nr_s_actors").multiselect("refresh");

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $.each(data,function(index,value)
    {
            var id="id_actor_"+value[0];
            //Assume the var id is correctly set to the id of the option. 
            $("#"+id).prop("selected", true);
    });
    $("#nr_s_actors").multiselect("refresh");
```